# Posting fetched data in database

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to fetch user info through a form and then insert same data in the table 'orders'.
Everything looks correct, but there is an error showing total_cost is undefined.
I tried declaring it globally as well.

total_cost should be the quantity selected by the user in the form multiplied by the price of the product which is fetched from the database.

**Here is the app.js post request:**

```
    // post create_order page
app.post("/create_order", function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var quantity = req.body.quantity;
    var email = req.body.email;

    // fetching price from menu table
    var sql = "select Price from menu where Name=?";
    db.query(sql,[name], function(err, result){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else if(result==0){
            console.log("No items found!!!")
        }else{
            console.log(result)
            console.log(Price)
            var total_cost = result;
            console.log(total_cost  )
        }
    })

    // Updating the order table
    let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    let order = {
        Item : name,
        Quantity : quantity,
        TotalCost : total_cost,
        Date : today,
        email : user
    }
    sql1 = "Insert into orders SET ?";
    db.query(sql1, order, function(err, result2){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            res.redirect("/orders");
        }
    })
})
```

**Here is the corresponding order form used to fetch data:**

```
    <!-- //Order form goes here -->
  <div class="orderform"> 
    <form action="/create_order" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Item</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
          <%result.forEach(function(result){%>
            <option><%=result.Name%></option>
          <%})%>
    
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">quantity</label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="quantity" min="1" max="10">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
      </div>
```

**Screenshot of error page:**
[Error page I am getting upon submitting the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqz88.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You defined your variable inner-scope; this will cause issues!

```
                let profile = 20;

                function call() {
                    console.log(profile); // == 20
                    let profile2 = 26;
                }
                call();
                console.log(profile2); // undefined in other words your error.
```

If it's not a scope issue, then it's certainly the data you're grabbing from data-base is incorrect. Double check the query.

Comment: Assuming your console.log on the data, was AOK to pass-along no issues there or "undefined" error; try defining your total_cost variable just below email. var total_cost = undefined; that should give it global scope like email.